# Htaccess with Angular2 to force SSL and fix routing

Tags: .htaccess

So I have two issues to resolve with my NG2 app:

1. When routes are refreshed, I get a page not found error
2. When a non-SSL route is accessed I want to re-direct to SSL.

**This fixes the broken routing:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

**This forces SSL. However when included with the above code, it no longer works.**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

How do I get these two conditions to work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my final solution.

This includes cashing, gzipping etc to make your app super fast!

```
#REDIRECT ROUTES TO INDEX (fixes broken routes with angular)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
#ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# SET EXPIRE HEADERS TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2 week"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I did a work-around so that when the page loads on http it simply replaces http with https. I know its not very elegant and it loads the page twice, but I thought of sharing it. Maybe someone can help with a pure htaccess solution.

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    location: Location;

    ngOnInit() {
        if (location.protocol === 'http:') {
            window.location.href = location.href.replace('http', 'https');
        }
    }
}
```